# How to do you find out default .Net dll rootkit invasion?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

How do you find out if your default `.net` dll is changed/modified/hacked?

Example taking `System.Console.WriteLine` to explain what I mean.

If `WriteLine()` is code injected to write output twice something like the following,

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello Programmers");
Output:
Hello Programmers
Hello Programmers
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would verify the integrity of any other software on your computer: check it against a trusted source after you have made sure, that the checking tool can be trusted. This is somewhat of a catch-22. Basically, you need to get better protection than your attacker, which depending on the attacker might be somewhere between dead easy and absolutely impossible.

As a first band-aid, try to deinstall and reinstall the framework and hope that the internet connection to Microsoft is still a trusted source on your computer.

Comment: I'd move suspect files (e.g framework dll:s in this case) to a sandbox somewhere and run binary diffs to known untampered files, as well as some checksum tests. Bottom line for .NET is that it is dead easy to tamper with the framework files but only after the machine is completely compromised anyway. The signing of assemblies in the GAC does not offer (good) protection from tampering. Here is a step by step hack http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/windowsnet/dotnet-framework-rootkits-backdoors-framework-32954?show=dotnet-framework-rootkits-backdoors-framework-32954&cat=windowsnet

Answer (score 1):

Note that not everything needs to be "injected" in order for you to get strange output.

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that replicates your problem without anything but normal legal .NET code:

```
void Main()
{
    Inject();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello Programmers");
}

public static void Inject()
{
    Console.SetOut(new InjectedTextWriter(Console.Out));
}

public class InjectedTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly TextWriter _InternalWriter;

    public InjectedTextWriter(TextWriter internalWriter)
    {
        _InternalWriter = internalWriter;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return _InternalWriter.Encoding;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string text)
    {
        _InternalWriter.Write(text);
        _InternalWriter.Write(text);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        _InternalWriter.WriteLine(text);
        _InternalWriter.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Here i can see the code, but what if I don't have the code and I am finding some funny behavior happening.